# Sharepoint 2010 List Settings

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, custom-list, list-form

I am Using a List in which i created Approval Required Column as Choice(Drop Down) with values Yes or No. Also i have a People Picker Column. The objective is the people picker must be disabled or hide if the value No is being selected and people picker must be available when the value Yes is selected from the choice(Drop Down). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have tagged SharePoint Designer, I would recommend adding some Javascript or jQuery to your form that will enable/disable/hide/show the People Picker based on changes to Approval Required.

For more information and other options, see [Dynamic columns based on rows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4043241/27482).